# Sending json data to backend via HTTP POST in Ionic 4 not working. [Notice: Trying to get property of non-object]

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, http-post, ionic4

I try to send http request via http post in Ionic 4 to my PHP backend through URL`http://myexamplehost#1.com/api` and it gives me back `Notice : trying to get property of non object...`.

When i send my json data through URL `http://myexamplehost#1.com/api` via postman it works just fine. I'm guessing my json data sent via http post in Ionic 4 is somehow wrong.

So i try to send my json data through my other URL `https://myexamplehost#2.com/api` via http post in Ionic 4 and long behold it works just fine.

Here's what the json i sent via postman :

```
{
  "id": "",
  "date": "2019-09-09",
  "name": "jason"
}
```

And here's what i sent via http post in Ionic 4 page.ts:

```
  mydata: Idata = {
    id:string;
    date:string;
    name:string
  }

   saveData(){
     this.dk.insertData(this.mydata).subscribe((result:any)=>{
       console.log(result['_body']);
     });

  }
```

Here's what the service method look like :

```
insertData(data:Idata){
    return this.http.post(this.configUrl+'?ins=true',data,{
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
    }
    });
```

Here's what the backend look like :

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
    print_r(json_encode($request));
//    echo json_encode($request->name."-".$request->date);
//    echo json_encode($request->tgl);
    $result = $obj->insData("example_tb","null,'".date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->date))."','".$request->name."'");
```

So what i really want to know is that is it a CORS issues or is it a code issues in my situation right there? Because i do get an error message of `origin has been blocked by CORS policy` in a console though. How do i fix this issues?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point that **Access-Control-Request-Method** is a request header that is set by the browser on CORS preflight requests, and it can only have one value.

Where **The Access-Control-Allow-Methods** is a CORS response header, returned by backend.

Replace

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
```

With

```
'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST'
```

Comment: I've tried to change the headers in service as your suggestion but it is still not working. Same error in console. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myexamplehost#1.com/api' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Check updated answer.
In general, just make sure that you set **CORS** headers.

Add some extra logs in the backend side, to make sure that designed code is executed.

Make sure that response headers for you ajax request contains CORS headers

Comment: Still not working. But i get a slightly different error though `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.` What went wrong there?

Comment: Make sure that you are returning correct CORS headers.
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');`

Comment: Isn't that what am exactly doing in my backend on my earlier post?

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for Ionic 4.

app.module.ts
İmport HttpClientModule

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Add HttpClientModule to imports.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent],
entryComponents: [],
imports: [HttpClientModule],
```

Now on your other page.
Mine ucak.page.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

SendDataFu(){
    
    
    

     let postData =  {
      user: "doctoravatar@yahoo.com",
      t: "vlIj",
      zip: 94089,
      forecast: 7
  }
   
     this.http.post("https://json.penzance.org/request", postData,{observe: 'response'})
       .subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
        
        }, error => {
         console.log(error);
       });
       
   }
```

Comment: why to use headers if it is not used anywhere?